# inline svg doesn't want to stretch in ie11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, internet-explorer-11

So, I have an inlined svg that is absolutely positioned inside a container.
I want the svg to stretch so that it fills up the entire with of the container.

I've set the aspect ratio of the container to something else than the ratio of the svg and positioned the svg to the bottom of the container so that the top of the svg will be cropped.

Works well in ff/chrome/safari but then i tested it in IE11 and it doesn't stretch all the way... Any ideas of how to achieve this in IE?

Here's the code:
http://niklasholmberg.se/temp/svgtest.html

Thanks

Comment: svgtest.html is no longer available on that server, it might be a good idea to re-upload it to a JSFiddle or remove the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
```

… to:

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax slice"
```

That makes IE consistent with the other browsers.

### Fiddle